# couldn't get Cypress code coverage report on vue and nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, cypress, code-coverage

I am using babel-plugin-Istanbul to the instrument my code. When do I add the plugin to nuxt.config.js always get a compile error on the web app? Does anyone have a working example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I could not configure cypress + istanbul + nuxt, following cypress tutorial, then I found this: https://github.com/n79s/nuxt-cypress-coverage-sample. This package easily solved my problem.